# Replace string in file using VB.net - case insensitive

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, replace

Given the following partial file example :

```
<SellGrey>True</SellGrey>
<SellWhite>false</SellWhite>
<SellGreen>false</SellGreen>
<SellBlue>false</SellBlue>
```

What is the best method to do a case-insensitive search and replace, while keeping the proper case on output.

For example:

```
<SellGrey>True</SellGrey>
```

or

```
<Sellgrey>tRue</Sellgrey>
```

would be what I am searching for, but the replacement, would always be :

```
<SellGrey>False</SellGrey>
```

---

Lastly, please do not get hung up on the "tags" as the file is malformed xml so reading/writing xml would bugger things up. Please look at the strings as just that -- a case-insensitive string search and replace, on a line by line basis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way for VB to determine that Sellgray should be formatted as SellGray. Would all tags be SellSomething?

Comment: No, the files are around 50 to 150,000 lines long ... various 'tags' .. it's really a pseudo language, and not true xml, else i would just use an xmlreader/writer to change the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide much detail about the tags, I used a dictionary for proper casing.

```
Dim input as String = "<Sellgrey>tRue</Sellgrey>"
Dim pattern as String = "<(?<tag>.+)>(?<value>(true|false))</.+>"

'building a dictionary to specify how to proper case
Dim tagFormatter as new Dictionary(Of String, String)
tagFormatter.Add("sellgrey", "ShellGrey")
tagFormatter.Add("sellwhite", "SellWhite")
tagFormatter.Add("sellgreen", "SellGreen")
tagFormatter.Add("sellblue", "SellBlue")

'build the new string using lambda
Dim result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, _
    Function(m) String.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", _
        tagFormatter(m.Groups("tag").Value.ToLower), _
        If(m.Groups("value").Value = "true", "True", "False")), _
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Basically, the malformed xml file contains various other tags like  <Mailboxes>
 </Mailboxes>  -- will your code leave everything else untouched ?  ...  is the entire final string result stored in "result" as a string .. or of just the values replaced ? ...

Comment: It will throw error, as other tags wont be found in the `tagFormatter`. `Regex.Replace` will not affect the orignal string unless u re-assign it.

Comment: I am looking for essentially the same thing as search & replace in a file in Notepad++ .. where it only changes what i search for, leaving the rest of the file in tact, but as a complete file, not just the changed resulting line.  Hope that helps clarify.

Comment: A dumbed down version of this question, would be replacing "bob" in a file that containts "tom" 7000 timex mixed in with other content. The result should be the same file, except with all instances of "tom" no longer present since "bob" was used to replace the 7000 instances of "tom". Result contains the full string of the entire file.